# Размещение изображения на странице сайта

Tags: css

При верстке макета столкнулся с такой задачкой. Пробую размещать выделенный элемент внутри контейнера применяя свойство `position: absolute;` Но тогда появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки при уменьшении экрана. Смещать же элемент медиа-запросами нельзя,это нарушит дизайн сайта. Существуют ли какие решения данного вопроса? Или это промах дизайнера?

[image: размещение элемента]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите его в контейнер с шириной 100%, и поставьте у контейнера `overflow:hidden;` и `position: relative;` или `position: absolute;` . Высоту контейнера установите так, чтобы картинка влезла целиком.

```css
body{padding:0; margin:0;}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="abs" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

Есть еще вариант установить `overflow-x: hidden;` у `body`. Однако проследите, чтобы это не вызвало проблем в дальнейшем.

```css
body{
  padding:0; margin:0;  
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
 
  <img class="abs" src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

Comment: overflow:hidden; будет обрезать изображение сверху и снизу

Comment: @soledar10 добавил комментарий по этому поводу

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Действительно,все работает как надо.